# Question related to "construct validity"

Tags: philosophy-of-science, construct-validity

Yet another quiz question. I feel so ignorant when I get such quizzes :(. The lecture notes are written in a non pedagogical way. This course is a compulsory course. 
I would be happy to hear your comments.

> Which of following statements about construct validity are true? Select one or more alternatives below.
>
> 1. The construct validity of a concept is a measure of how value-laden it is.
> 2. Construct validity is the degree to which a test measures the property that it purports to be measuring.
> 3. Construct validity can be considered a measure of how realiable an operationalization is.
> 4. Construct validity is a measure of the extent to which an operationalization is theory-dependent.

---

My attempt:
1. False,
2. True,
3. True,
4. False.

Am I correct?

Comment: Remember to add your own thinking/efforts in the question. The pedagogues around here don't much care for outright doing a student's homework...

Comment: See [Construct validity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Construct_validity).

Comment: @christo183: thank you for your feedback. please see my attempt. Would you like to give me feedback? thank you.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Thank you Mauro.